# Which platforms do I need to add for my Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

I'm creating a Facebook app. It is an online survey and consists of some forms that the users have to answer. It runs on my server and is basically nothing but a common website. The site has been programmed to dynamically adapt to all mobile and desctop browsers and screen sizes, so **the same URL provides the app for all platforms**.

When I register my app with Facebook, I have the option to "Add Platforms".

### Which platforms do I need to add? All? None? Just "Website"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how exactly you want to use your app... A good starting point are the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/register-facebook-application/ which give you a first overview.

The app screen is similar to this:

[image]

I guess in your case, you'd need at least "App on Facebook" if you want to use it within the FB platform. If you want to use the Facebook Login, you need to configure "Website with Facebook Login" as well, and if you want mobile accessibility too, "Mobile Web" as well.

Comment: Thank you. All I want is the user id (to avoid duplicate participation). Do I need "App on Facebook" for that? Or what exactly does "App on Facebook" do that "Website with Facebook Login" doesn't already provide? I don't want to post on FB walls, add friends etc., just make sure the same person doesn't participate twice.

Comment: If you just use "Website with Facebook Login", you can also receive User Access Tokens etc. The question I'm asking myself is where is the link between your "Facebook app" and the FB platform? Is there any?

Comment: There isn't really any link. All I want is to make use of FB to identify individuals and avoid duplicates. Duplicates would falsify the research, but since participants get paid some might be inclined to get paid twice. Otherwise there is no interaction between FB and my survey.

Comment: I guess then "Website with Facebook Login" and "Mobile Web" will be fine.